# Rename the folder of document directory

Tags: iphone, ios

This could be easy, but I am not getting the problem.

 I am using below code to rename the folders of document directory and is working fine except one case.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
    NSArray * arrAllItems = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:NULL]; // List of all items
    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrAllItems objectAtIndex:tagSelected]]];

    NSString *newDirectoryName = txtAlbumName.text; // Name entered by user
    NSString *oldPath = filePath;
    NSString *newPath = [[oldPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newDirectoryName];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        // handle error
    }
```

Now, my problem is if `there is a folder named "A"(capital letter A) and I am renaming it to "a" (small letter a), then it is not working and giving an error.` 
 I am not getting where the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that Unix is not Windows. File paths are case sensitive.

Comment: What error it giving?

Comment: @H2CO3, that's true, but how it is related to my question? oldPath is "../Documents/Photos/A" and newPath is "../Documents/Photos/a".

Comment: @CRDave, Error is "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)"

Comment: @H2CO3: The problem would not occur if the file system is case sensitive. It occurs because HFS+ (on OS X) is case insensitive (but case preserving).

Comment: @H2CO3 if it is case sensitive then OP would not have this problem right?

Comment: @MartinR As far as I know, HFS+ on iOS is never case-insensitive. (The question is tagged iOS, so I don't understand the relevance of OS X being case insensitive.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Well my guess is that OP tested this in the iOS Simulator, which uses the OS X (case insensitive) file system.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli, I am sorry, but what is OP?

Comment: @PiyushDubey: "OP" is an abbreviation for "original poster" (of the question), so that would be *you*.

Comment: @PiyushDubey So, did you use the simulator instead of a real device?

Comment: @MartinR Fair enough. (Another reason why I hate the simulator.)

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, I used simulator in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HFS+ file system (on OS X) is *case insensitive*, but *case preserving*.
That means if you create a folder "A" and then check if there is a folder "a", you will get
"yes" as an answer.

The file manager `moveItemAtPath:toPath:...` checks first if the destination path already
exists and therefore fails with

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x7126dc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"
```

One workaround would be to rename the directory to some completely different name first:

```
A --> temporary name --> a
```

But a much easier solution is to use the BSD `rename()` system call, because that
can rename "A" to "a" without problem:

```
if (rename([oldPath fileSystemRepresentation], [newPath fileSystemRepresentation]) == -1) {
    NSLog(@"%s",strerror(errno));
}
```

Note that the problem occurs only on the iOS Simulator, not on the device, because
the device file system is *case sensitive*.

**Swift:**

```
let result = oldURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { oldPath in
    newURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { newPath in
        rename(oldPath, newPath)
    }
}
if result != 0 {
    NSLog("%s", strerror(errno))
}
```

Comment: @PiyushDubey: You are welcome. - But note that rename() *replaces* any existing destination because it does *not* check first if the destination exists or not.